# Setting environment variable in local_setup.bash from ament_cmake package

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to set/modify an environment variable when the user sources the `local_setup.bash` from compiling my packages with `colcon`. I haven't succeeded at finding how to do this.

My packages use the `ament_cmake` build method.

Reading https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/environment.html it seems there are some automated detections done by colcon, and `ament_cmake` generates its own `local_setup.bash`. But I do not find how to explicitly say 'set this variable' or if I should generate another script to be sourced, and how I should instruct colcon or ament_cmake to pick it up.

Thanks for any guidance.

Update 2021-05-08

It seems that adding contents to the `install/pkg/share/pkg/package.dsv` file should do it. Still not clear how to do this. I've read through https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/environment.html and https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html and I feel I am near the intended solution. Basically I need to make colcon aware of the existence of a new `.dsv` file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379485/setting-environment-variable-in-local_setup.bash-from-ament_cmake-package/) by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2021-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some more digging I finally found that what I need is `ament_environment_hooks`. This is also answered here: https://discourse.ros.org/t/execute-something-as-part-of-local-setup-bash-call/2790

Given that the first google hit is the source code itself and the second one is that question, and the rest are increasingly obscure souces in foreign script, I consider myself satisfied that as simple as it may be it wasn't obviously documented.

---

Originally posted by [amosteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35076/amosteo/) with karma: 43 on 2021-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1